# What does "being in credit" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, idioms

My University wrote me that they

```
can conform [my] account is currently in credit - £136.60.
```

Does this mean I have to pay them 136 Pound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to pay them.

If you are "in credit" then you have not spent all the money that the university holds for you.

The opposite of being "in credit" is being "in debt".

Answer (score 0):

It can be confusing sometimes.

In your account with your university, positive amounts will reflect money you own them, negative amounts will reflect money they owe you.

This is the opposite of amounts shown in your savings or checking account since the university is sending you a bill of what you *owe them*, your "debt" with them. If you owe them a negative amount, it becomes a double negative, and they in fact owe you money (for whatever reason).

So a £136.60 credit on your unversity account means that you have monies held by the university (possibly because you over paid or dropped a course?), and have a "credit" with the university. If you were to register for another course, the "credit" would offset some of the "debit" which would be charged to your account for the additional course.